# Why with Raspian 10 buster my locale keeps changing to POSIX on reboot?

Tags: keyboard

I have been trying hard to set my locale on my Raspberry Pi4 with Raspian 10 buster with these steps:

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8

export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_TYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8

sudo nano /etc/locale.gen
```

(uncommented en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8)

```
sudo update-locale en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

it does show the correct settings if I check with

locale

but as soon as I reboot, everything is reset to

```
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

How can I fix this, please?

also tried:

```
L='us' && sudo sed -i 's/XKBLAYOUT=\"\w*"/XKBLAYOUT=\"'$L'\"/g' /etc/default/keyboard
```

and

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
setxkbmap us
```

and

```
loadkeys us
```

and

```
apt-get install keyboard-configuration console-setup
console-setup
```

but as soon as I reboot, everything is reset again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is unclear. It could be as simple as file permissions.

You should not attempt to set locale manually (I used to do this on other Linux platforms so it SHOULD be possible).

There are tools in `raspi-config` which should make sure that the correct changes are applied, although these have had known problems (see https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=286940).
In my case these stubbornly set locale to en_US.UTF-8, which I only managed to fix by manually editing `/etc/default/locale`

You can re-run the initial Pi GUI setup tool with `sudo piwiz`

PS I just looked at my `/etc/default/locale` and noticed that YET AGAIN it was incorrect - presumably some of the updates since have affected it. I again corrected by manually editing. (The missing ".UTF-8" only caused problems over `ssh`.)